# google maps api - resize width on the left side

Tags: google-maps

As a German I find it hard to explain, I hope you get my problem:

When you resize your browser window when [Google Maps](https://maps.google.de/) is open you will see how the map gets cut on the right. Or to say it in other words: the coordinates of the left corners remain the same when you resize the whole window.
When I just dynamically resize the map-canvas (in my code) the same effect happens.

Now: In Google Maps there is a panel on the left you can show or hide. When you click "show" (or "hide") something different can be seen, the coordinates of the right corners stay the same, even though the map gets resized.

As I described a "normal" div resize won't do it.

So: How to dynamically change the width of the map with the coordinates of the right corners staying the same?

I really hope you get it :)

Thanks a lot,

timon

Comment: If you look the left corner does not "_stay_" the same when the panel is collapsed. For what you want to achieve you could try to listen the `bounds_changed` event of the `map` object and calculate the new bounds that include the _NorthEast_ corner then set the new bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve you could try to listen the `bounds_changed` event of the map object and calculate the new bounds that include the NorthEast corner then set the new bounds. The difficulty reside to calculate the SouthWest corner which involve complicated maths.

Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>Kml Layer</title>
       <style type="text/css">
            html,  body{height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
            #map-container{ height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width:500px; min-height:300px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span id="coordinates">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="map-container"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">
            var map;
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var $mapContainer = $("#map-container"),
                $coordinates = $("#coordinates");

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.4199865, -76.519775)
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map($mapContainer[0], mapOptions);

                var oldBounds, setBounds = function() {
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
                    console.log("bounds_changed");
                    var newBounds = map.getBounds();

                    if(oldBounds){                      
                        var northEast = oldBounds.getNorthEast(),
                           // the calcul of the south west corner is somewhat dificult I'm taking arbitrary the southwest corner of the 'newBounds' object
                           // only to get the code to work, but this point have to be recalculated taking in account the div you're resizing.
                            southWest = newBounds.getSouthWest(),
                            newMapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

                        map.fitBounds(newMapBounds);                        
                    }

                    oldBounds = newBounds;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", setBounds);
                    },0);                     
                },
                listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", setBounds);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```